# disappear project files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-project-file

Suddenly, all the sub-files of a particular project disappeared from the time I re-run Eclipse.

There was no specific error message when running, there's just ".project" file, "bin" folder, and "/bin/.project" file's only left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbEeU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzaxI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo0yM.png)

using Eclipse 2022-03 version.

I'm checking the Eclipse execution log, but I'm wondering if there's a similar case, so post it first

Comment: The deletion was most likely not by Eclipse but by something else while Eclipse and the Java application were running. This would explain the leftover `bin` folder whose files are blocked while running the Java application, and the `.project` file that is restored on exiting Eclipse. Does right-clicking the project folder and choosing _Restore from Local History..._ help, at least to restore some of what has disappeared? By the way, Eclipse 2022-03 is quite outdated. Please upgrade.